# Remove duplicate items in the ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need to delete some items in a WPF listbox, I use this code :

```
while (ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
  ListBox.Items.Remove(ListBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

But the problem is that my listbox contains several same items, for example :

```
chocolate
milk
orange
milk
banana
apple
milk
```

If I select the 2nd occurence of milk at the 4th position and try to delete it with the given code, it will remove the first occurence of milk at the 2nd position (not selected) AND the selected 2nd occurence of milk at the 4th position.

I have also tried with :

```
while (ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
  ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox.Items.IndexOf(ListBox.SelectedItem));
}
```

But the result is the same.

Could anybody give me a clue on this ?

Comment: Please don't edit "Solved" into the title of your question.  If someone provided an answer that solves your problem, you can mark that answer as Accepted.  This will create a visible queue in the list of questions that indicates it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if (ListBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
   ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```